# Factorization Issue (RSA)

Tags: rsa, factorization

I simply need to find P or Q primes for a big number.

```
7557912574608535164426718292058021255641310207187633095795069445700059210248050757270234679993673844203148013173091173786572116639
```

Is there any way I do this programatically with the use of some high-level language that can go behind **O(2^(n^C))**?

Comment: Do you realize that RSA encryption is based on the fact that a it's virtually impossible to find P and Q for large numbers?

Comment: I'm quite aware but there must be a way to go round this.

Comment: If you could get around it, then RSA encryption would be useless. The only way to crack it is with an extreme amount of computing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is 130 digits long, which is within the bounds of what can reasonably be done with modern algorithms and fast processors. Look at [Jeff Gilchrist's](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide.html) tutorial to find out how. Expect to spend a month or more getting a factorization.